# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' error in Flask app even if numpy present.

Tags: python, numpy, flask

I'm developing a flask application in which I want to use numpy. I used `import numpy as np` but when I run the application I get this error, 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. I do have numpy install in python and also cross-checked it with importing numpy in python cmd as below:

```
C:\Users\Zirak Mistry>python
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

No error after executing the command `import numpy` means that numpy is installed in python and is working properly. Yet when I'm importing numpy into my flask application, I'm getting errors. Why so? please help.

Comment: This might sound dumb but have you tried closing your application completely and restarting it?

Comment: @ycx Yes I did try it, but it did not work. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the Python you are using to run Flask is not the same as the one you tested the `import numpy` with, and numpy is installed in the wrong Python.

You can use `sys.executable` to determine where you are running Python from. Try both in your Flask app and in cmd to see if they are the same.

If they really are the same, it's also possible that the Flask app has changed where it is searching for modules. This can be changed programmatically. If it's not on `sys.path` the normal import mechanism won't find it.

Comment: never used sys.executable and never heard about it. Could you please explain how to use it?

Comment: Thank-you, I've figured out how to use sys.executable and also got my problem solved.