# No module named numpy in Flask

Tags: apache, numpy, flask

I need to use Numpy on EC2 instance that runs Flask with WSGI-py3, which can be accessed over HTTP.

After setting up everything needed, I can see the page in the browser. However, later I am installing Numpy using pip3 and now the service breaks with the following error in /var/log/apache2/error.log `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`, however I can import numpy in python3 without any problems

What could be done to be able to import numpy in Flask application?

**EDIT:**
It is confusing.. If I list all Python versions installed, I get:

```
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1018 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsondiff
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3661 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpatch
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1342 May  1  2016 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpointer
   4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 Nov 15  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema
4424 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Apr 18 01:56 /usr/bin/python3.6
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr 18 01:56 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
4424 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Apr 18 01:56 /usr/bin/python3.6m
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Apr 18 01:56 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
```

- `pip3` seems to be connected to `python3.6`
- `/usr/local/bin/flask` uses `#!/usr/bin/python3`
- If I install numpy using `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install numpy` I still have the same problem

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955580/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-error-in-flask-app-even-if-numpy-pr

Comment: @MustafaKemal there are two Python versions. However, if I install numpy for both, I still get the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using virtual environment in EC2 has helped:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo ln -sT /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo ln -sT /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
sudo pip install flask
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
mkdir ~/flaskapp
sudo ln -sT ~/flaskapp /var/www/html/flaskapp
cd ~/flaskapp
virtualenv flask --python=python3
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
.....
sudo pip3 install numpy
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably means, the Python interpreter which runs Flask is a different than the Python interpreter which you have installed `numpy` into.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with AWS.

Basically, you have to figure out how to find the Python interpreter you installed Flask with.

Comment: There are two Python versions, but even when installing numpy for both I still have the same problem

Comment: Could be there are three python versions? Or one your installs not going correctly?